# Xampp MySql Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, wordpress, xampp, localhost, innodb

my Xampp MySql won't start. Elsewhere in this forum was has been advised to change the file name C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 to ibdata1.bak and turn off the Xampp. But it did not help. Is there a way to fix this?

```
2020-09-17 17:19:47 2 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=33, page number=1] log sequence number 402782 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 47064.
2020-09-17 17:19:47 2 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2020-09-17 17:19:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 47055; transaction id 347965
2020-09-17 17:19:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-09-17 17:19:47 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-09-17 17:19:47 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=243] log sequence number 336525986 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 47064.
2020-09-17 17:19:47 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
2020-09-17 17:19:47 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=309] log sequence number 332378035 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 47064.
2020-09-17 17:19:47 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-09-17 17:19:47 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespac
```

Answer (score 0):

Your files (maybe log files) and the time of your PC have conflict!

> log sequence number 402782 is in the **future**!

1. check your PC time and sync it with real time!
2. remove all files which have a date-time more than your PC date-time (if possible! if not, create a new one in a proper date). For example your PC date is 2019-xx-xx and your files is 2020-xx-xx.

Comment: Weird the time is correct in my system. But whether deleting files will not destroy my databases?

Comment: Yes! it will. Just check which files have wrong timestamp. If they are logs remove them. If Not copy your files in new ones which have correct timestamp. After that just move your files to new place (To have a backup of them)

Comment: I have to check every file in xampp folder?